# horizontal UIScrollView with paging

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am looking for an open source library out there on github that does horizontal UIScrollView with paging that kind of does it the way UITableView does it (reusing cells). Any suggestions out there?

Comment: @ Bill the Lizard why you deleted my answer from this post???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some projects :

https://github.com/TheVole/HorizontalTable

https://github.com/rickharrison/RHHorizontalTableView

https://github.com/andrewgubanov/OrientedTableView

https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView

Comment: none of that does pagination and it is a UITableView. I am looking for a UIScrollView subclass that can do pagination. So I can swipe left and right easily

Comment: @xonegirlz What do you mean by pagination? Page numbers? In the question you talk about "paging"?

Answer (score 2):

use this

https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView

i used it for my own app, which works great, with a few easy tweaks you can make it do what u want.

it supports paging for horizontal and vertiacl gridding, returns value after each page, and manymore